# Joomla 3 slider

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have put an image slider in Joomla 3.0 that is ARI image slider, it was the best reveiwed slider in all I found for Joomla 3.

That slider is working well in Joomla 2.5 as I tested it there as well but when I use it in Joomla 3 the slider has a dotted panel above it. Also the slider closes after the first slideshow and the panel remains. I am attaching the screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5XjC.jpg

I'm including the template in the command by:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" />
```

Is there any other slider that will work well for Joomla 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I just used anythingslider and inserted the `<ul id="slider"></ul>` in the default.php in my own custom component `/com_slider/views/sliders/tmpl/default.php`
wrapped in `<?php if($this->items) : ?>`

seems to work ok.